# Find TopHat accepted_hits.bam mapped to transcriptome and genome separetly

Tags: bioinformatics

I did a `tophat/2.0.13` alignment giving both genomic and transcriptome inputs and  would like to know how I can find %reads mapped to transcriptome and %ampped to the genome in my `accepted_hits.bam` output file.

Is there a straight forward way of doing this? `samtools flagstat` only give me overall mapping % and does not distinguish between genomic and transcriptomic alignment.

Below is the script I used to for the tophat alignment:

```
tophat -G GRCm38_p4.gtf --min-anchor 8 --min-isoform-fraction 0.15     
--library-type fr-unstranded --transcriptome-index known_mm10 -p 12 
-o ${stdout} /Bowtie2Index/genome /R1.fastq /R2.fastq
```

Any resources/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Note that there is now a beta bioinformatics stackexchange site where this question might receive answers: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/